# Why does NSNumberFormatter not accept plus number

Tags: ios

```
if(![myNumberFormatter numberFromString:[tempColumn objectAtIndex:j]])
{
    numericalColumns[j] = NO;
    if(j == 8)
    {
        NSLog(@" non numerical value in column 8 i = %d object = %@ ", i , [tempColumn           objectAtIndex:j]);
    }
}
```

What I find:

```
0   good
-19.49883745    good
+38.85928608    bad
+46.94000154    bad
-0.36042119     good
+38.30408636    bad
-44.29029741    good
+26.91823821    bad
-79.06183133    good
-16.69693020    good
```

Comment: did you try just `38.85928608`?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
[myNumberFormatter setPositivePrefix:@"+"];
```

before calling numberForString

Comment: Note that this makes it accept `+3`, but it can no longer accept `3`